# как получить координаты элемента UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

как получить координаты элемента UserControl (то есть на usercontrol есть два эллипса и нужно получить координаты одного из них) относительно холста например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
var point = myControl.TransformToVisual(myCanvas).Transform(new Point());
```

Где `myControl` — элемент, координаты которого необходимо получить, а `myCanvas` — элемент, относительно которого необходимо получить.

Имейте ввиду, что таким образом вы получите логические координаты, не зависящие от настроек масштабирования Windows.